# Securing connection strings and app settings in an Azure App - how to use them locally

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, web-config, connection-string

In my web app which is hosted as an Azure App Service, I have the following in my `web.config` for testing:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ProductionConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=tcp:something.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User Id=admin@sssdddr;Password=Pass@word1;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I'm trying to follow some basic security best practices here, so I've moved my connection string up to the `Application Settings` section of my web app:

[image]

This particular setting is a bad example because ideally I'd only ever have `ProductionConnection` stored in Azure and never used locally - but for other connection strings and `appSettings` used both locally and in production that should should be protected, how should I handle the values when developing locally?

Comment: `how should I handle the values when developing locally` Do you mean developer should not see the connection string value?

Comment: @Win I mean the connection string value / app setting should not be baked into the application's `bin` directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I mean the connection string value / app setting should not be baked
>   into the application's bin directory

Connection strings are normally located inside web.config file. web.config will never be inside bin folder; we normally place it inside application's root folder.

I believe you mean storing sensitive information like username and password to access SQL Server. You cannot hide connection string and settings from developers who is debugging the application.

In corporate environment, we *(developers)* use ***Windows Authentication*** to access SQL Server.

Comment: Say you have an appSetting that gives you the azure blob storage container name.  You want to protect this from attackers, just because.  Devs can see it, no problem.  You add your app setting to azure so that it gets injected into your `app.config` at runtime.  But the value hasn't been removed from `app.config` because devs still need it.  How then do you fully protect against someone decompiling your app and accessing "sensitive" information.

Comment: In Azure above connection string, there is [App setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZu4W.png). We normally keep App setting there.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Does your developer use azure connection strings and settings while developing local?

Comment: Settings sure - like a twilio api key, or a stripe secret key, for example

Comment: Well, you will need separate testing accounts for those. Ideally, we should not check in sensitive information to source repository.

Answer (score 2):

if you're looking for securing secrets/connection strings from developer, go for [Azure Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-get-started) which is designed to secure all your secrets from everyone. Each secret will be exposed as a URI to end developer to consume via REST.

for this, you need to [register your application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-integrating-applications) with Azure AD as KeyVault would request for AD Token to provide secrets.